# anaconda pip doesn't use .pypirc

Tags: python, pip

I'm not able to install a python package that's present in a private Azure DevOps artifact feed. I've added the feed as an extra index-server in my (windows) profile directory's `.pypirc` file but that doesn't seem to help. I'm sure the contents of that file is correct (read below), so what's the problem?

I have a python Azure Function project in VSCode. VSCode created a .venv directory. It contains python.exe and pip.exe in its Scripts subdirectory. When I open a cmd prompt, go to that directory and perform my `pip install <my private wheel>`, it works just fine! That pip does pick up `.pypirc` which then also must have the correct content.

Why doesn't the `C:\tools\Anaconda3\envs\scipytest\Scripts\pip.exe` pick up the .pypirc file? Note that this pip is able to do it when I using the `--extra-index-url` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip doesn't read `.pypirc` -- whatever success you had must have had some other explanation than that

here's a summary of [the files pip uses](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file)

for windows in particular it'll look at these directories:

- user level: `%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini`
- virtualenv level: %VIRTUAL_ENV%\pip.ini
- global: `C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini`
- or if `PIP_CONFIG_FILE` is set it will respect that

Comment: That was it. Thanks. Interesting that I had a setup where .pyirc did the trick,

Comment: The reason the one pip install did work was because there was a pip.ini I didn't notice in the .venv environment...